# How to transfer huge files between Android phones only with ES File Explorer and Wi-Fi?

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer

I have few HD movies each occupying around 1Gb to be transferred from one Android phone to another.  I've read the question [How to transfer files over Wi-Fi without a hotspot](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25898/how-to-transfer-files-over-wifi-without-a-hotspot) and its answers. Even before reading the question, I explored transferring one of the above said movie file from my LGP500 to my Nexus 7 (2012) successfully using ES Explorer and Wi-Fi.

Now at my work, I am trying to do the same to my friend's Micromax A110 and all my efforts goes vain. I tired to make Micromax A110 to host a random Wi-Fi network and I join my LGP500 to it before transfer. After selecting the file and choosing `Send` option, the upcoming UI just shows `scanning...` and a progress bar goes on and on. There are no visibility settings like Bluetooth in Wi-Fi transfer mode.

I tried the reverse the connection and again it failed.

I am bit puzzled and think I am missing something obvious.  **Can someone help by providing a step by step guide to transfer files between two Android devices with ES File explorer using Wi-Fi?**

I am sticking with Wi-Fi because the transfer rate was too good. I saw near to 10 MB/s. And I do not want to install other apps as I find ES File explorer available with many of my friends.

Some trivia:

- My LG P500 is rooted and runs stock v2.3.3
- My Nexus 7 is rooted and runs stock v4.3
- My friend's A110 is not rooted and runs stock 4.0.1
- Size of the file that I transferred successfully is 600Mb and face
  failure on the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Es File Explorer doesnt work, I suggest that you use SuperBeam: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.majedev.superbeam

It uses Wifi Direct Technology to transfer files at wifi speeds, and the wifi direct connection is initialized by scanning a qr code generated by the app of by touching them together with nfc on.  You can "Share" the file with Superbeam and opening the app starts the reciever end of the communication

Comment: This app says it is not compatible with my LG P500, running v2.3.3. I successfully installed it in my nexus 7, but I could not even find it in Google play store in P500. When clicked on the link in the answer, play store explicitly says the incompatibility message.

Comment: Now with recent versions of ES File Explorer, I am able to transfer successfully. The issue that I still face is that the app becomes unresponsive during a Wi-Fi scan giving a false impression that the app is not working or crashed.

Comment: @Narayanan The best way to do it is have both devices connected to the same wifi and share over lan. That is what worked for me : Here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xp4qg_QoNEM

Answer (score 2):

If you open ES Explorer select the file you want to share then click more "has the 3 dots vertical"  and select send "has a image of a phone with a double sided arrow" it will scan and find the device. Select the device and share. This is the only way I was able to get ES File Explorer to work with sharing. I am sharing between my Note 3 and Nexus 7 (2012).

Comment: This is the right answer and should be the accepted answer! Both phones must be on the same Wi-Fi network with ES file explorer open in order for the first phone to find the second

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 you can do this from Google's "Files" app directly. It has simple "send" and "receive" buttons and sets up peer-to-peer WiFi temporarily and securely with zero configuration hassle.